# Как вывести значение radio button?

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно получить значения полей профиля пользователя. Мне удалось вывести текстовые поля. Но поле radio button выводит id поля, а не его значение, то есть 1 а не Кот.
Например:
1 Кот
2 Собака

```
 '{tel}' => esc_html( $user_data->tel ),
 '{address}' => esc_html( $user_data->address ),
 '{text}' => esc_html( $user_data->text),
 '{radio}' => esc_html( $user_data->radio),
```

Как вывести значение radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос вызывает еще больше вопросов. Вам надо получить поля или вывести? Что содержит переменная $user_data? Как она формируется?

1. Если вам надо вывести, запишите в  $user_data->radio = 'Кот'
2. Если вам надо получить из html то radio button передает значение выделенного элемента в value в теге html. Если в value записано 1, php увидит 1. Если записано Кот php увидит Кот.

https://metanit.com/php/tutorial/3.3.php